# Add line numbers to TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

is it possible to set linenumbers to a document using TCPDF?.
In my case I'm using the MultiCell() method and I want to set a linenumbering.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself.
I extended the Tcpdf and copied the writer() method.
Then I added the $nl in each Cell() call.

```
$this->Cell($w, $h, $nl.' '.$tmpstr, 0, $ln, $align, $fill, $link, $stretch);
```

best regards